# Washing machine and oven connected at the same outlet

Tags: electrical

In the kitchen I have two 16 A wall sockets, and each has a power strip plugged into it ("max 3000 W" label). At present, the washing machine and the oven are connected together to one power strip, while the fridge and the microwave are connected to the other.

I was wondering: being the washing machine and the oven the most energy-intensive appliances, shouldn't they be connected to different sockets?
However, notice that they cannot actually run together, since the maximum load for homes here in Italy is 3 kW: if I start the washing machine while the oven is heating, the power supply gets interrupted.

Can I leave it as it is, or should I try to distribute better the load?

I'm renting, and obviously installing more wall socket would be the best, but it's not doable. Also complaining with the owner wouldn't be good advice.

Comment: You can't use power strip like this ,It might result in over current and tripping and power strips are meant to be used for temporary purposes. You have to directly plug into 16A wall sockets. so I'd suggest four 16A wall socket. One for each and again. Have a separate circuit box with trippers in the kitchen.

Comment: Unless the power strips are of high quality, I would get rid them for that use.  Most common strips are made more for light use devices.  Most washers(clothes) usually not that high of a power use, unless they heat water also.  Ovens are high power use and usually need their own circuit.  The electrostatic discharge might be concerning if it comes from the washer or you rubbing socks over carpet.

Comment: I'm shocked that, a) an oven doesn't trip a standard wall outlet circuit, and b) an oven has a plug that can be plugged into an outlet.  Is this some kind of *toaster* oven or something?

Comment: OP is in _Italy_ @Huesmann. Things are different there than they are here in the US...

Comment: What is the service spec for your "oven"? Is it, for instance, an oven/range (cook top) combo that's primarily serviced by gas as is common in Europe, but has a small electric service for starting and displaying a clock?

Comment: @King Adding sockets is the correct move, but whether OP can daisy chain new sockets or rerun new outlets is a major cost consideration. Italians get 230V so Ohm's law says this circuit may service some light duty appliances possibly with some GFCI. But I don't know Italian code.

Comment: @Huesmann in 230V countries a lot of appliances are sold to fit on a standard 16A circuit and to be plugged in to a standard outlet.  Ranges and ovens sold that way aren't always very *good* ones, but still, they are sold that way.

Comment: @Huesmann, my stove has gas burners and electric oven. The electric oven is powered by a boring 15A plug, 110V.

Comment: Don't do laundry when you cook. Microwave popping the fridge's circuit is prob best case; you'll know when you take your food out of the MW that the light's not on. - Diagram? or pictures of the spaghetti cords? There's two outlets on two different circuits? Or it's all the same circuit, so you're sol anyway? Are you popping the actual breaker or just the power strip?

Answer (score 7):

[ Preamble: I assume the oven is not a gas one (with a light or igniter) and I hope you would have said so if it was.  But it's a good callout in the comments and so I'll state my assumption here. ]

"Should I" is not a question that can be answered very well here, but here are some things you should consider:

- *Ideally* each one of these appliances should be on its own breaker and its own wall outlet.
- It's better not to use power strips for large appliances. Especially not a 3000W power strip for an oven that may use 3000W by itself!  And especially not for a fridge where the power strip is an unnecessary failure point that can cause your food to spoil.

If it is practical and within your budget to get an electrician to install some more breakers and wall outlets you should do that.

The fridge should be on its own circuit so that if a different appliance causes a breaker to pop open, your food won't spoil.

The oven should be on its own circuit because it (probably) easily uses 3000W by itself, and if you have something cooking you don't want to be unable to use the microwave or washer for hours on end!

The washer and microwave can probably share a 16A circuit, if that is allowed where you live.  You don't have ring mains in Italy right?  But if you do, you can definitely have the washer and microwave on one.

Also you didn't mention your cooktop ... is it a single unit with the oven?  Or somewhere else, with its own circuit or is it gas?    I'm asking because, if you do have an electrician do work, you should add more than one 16A circuit to the location of any electric cooktop, especially if combined with an oven.  Exactly what you should add, ask the electrician, it depends on your electric service.

Comment: This advice is based on US code, but it's also common sense advice and common sense applies no matter where in the world one lives! +1

Comment: There is actually nothing in my answer based on US code!   I was careful to cite practical reasons for my suggestions.   In fact, for all I know, these things may be required in Italy, or they may even be *disallowed*, to limit power use!  I tried to avoid those questions, though they are good ones.

Comment: And @FreeMan you didn't catch my 3000kW oven (now fixed)? :)

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right, and yes, I know you cited no code anywhere. I guess I've just gotten so used to seeing these types of recommendations that I assumed. I do fully support your answer and was trying to stave off criticism...

Comment: I assumed you were baking paint onto car parts! :D

Comment: @jay613 - one breaker for every 16A wall socket .. is it necessary ? I think one separate breaker for whole kitchen unit wouldn't be enough ? or atleast two heavywehights for one breaker would be enough

Comment: Thank you @jay613, I'm renting so I'm looking for a quick fix. 1) there's a breaker (from the power company) if the load goes above 3kW, 2) all washers here heat water, 3) I guess oven and washer are around 2kW each. Considering the fact that washing machine and oven CANNOT run together (over 3kW the breaker gets triggered), it is better to distribute the load (e.g., washer+fridge and oven+microwave), but in this case 2 appliances could run simultaneously on the same strip, or it's better to leave oven and washer on the same, since they would open the breaker if run together?

Comment: @King a separate breaker for the fridge is a precaution to reduce sources of failure causing food spoilage.  It is not necessary.  For everything else, it depends very much on the cooking appliance(s).  A *small* oven can certainly share a breaker with other things, but obviously in OP's case it cannot!  Larger cooking appliances use over 10kW, so obviously cannot share a 16A circuit or even use one on their own.

Comment: I wrote a second answer based on the information you added in the above comment.

Comment: "common sense applies no matter where in the world one lives!" but the constraints we live with differ. It's hard to be sure, but I always get the impression that compared to electrical installations in my native UK, US electrical installations are overspecified and mainland European ones are underspecified.

Comment: I've set power strips on fire more than once. Never seen or even heard of a breaker not failing-safe; that's their job. I'd get heavy duty cords and splitters. +1 to your second answer, that just tries to sort out this cord non-sense.

Comment: @PeterGreen  in absolute terms yes, but US homes are larger on average and in the southern half of the country air conditioning is an additional very large load even if all other major appliances are gas instead of electric (a stove/oven, clothes drier, and tanked water heater alone are enough that 100A is going to be marginal at best) so I suspect in terms of how much of the headline capacity is used the US and UK aren't far apart.

Answer (score 5):

I'm taking the unusual step of a second answer ... this one based on the additional comments that OP is a tenant, there is a 3kW limit on the entire apartment, and we accept that the owner will not address this.

My suggestion is to:

1. Use a single wall socket for all three of the laundry, microwave, and oven, and plug in only one of them at a time. Using the circuit breaker to police this constantly is not a good idea! The breaker can fail, resulting in a fire.
2. Buy a small countertop oven, around 1500W, and use that whenever possible.  This can better coexist with your other appliances.  Use the larger oven only when absolutely needed, and then you can plan its "electricity time".
3. If it turns out you can use your countertop oven together with the laundry, or the laundry together with the microwave, or whatever ... you can leave them all plugged in.  But again, don't leave the big oven plugged in relying on the circuit breaker to protect you *frequently*, don't use the power bar for the big oven, and preferably don't use any power bar for the fridge, so that the failure of a cheap power bar won't cause your food to spoil.

Comment: Thank you again, but unfortunately I cannot plug/unplug from the wall sockets since they are hidden behind the kitchen furniture. Taking a cue from what you say, I think my best option is to plug the oven to the wall, and the washing machine to a good strip (it is 3kW certified) with the rest of the appliances, but never use them when I do laundry. In fact, I cannot plug the washer to the wall, since it has a schuko plug, and that's not very common in Italy.